# start-cluster - Command failed: genesis create - */genesis.alonzo.spec.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: plutus, cardano-node, plutus-pab

After cloning latest cardano-node and running nix-shell successfully I get an error running start-cluster and different error if I run with sudo:

Do I need to download the latest genesis jason file? or set WORKBENCH_BACKEND?

````
[nix-shell:~/plutus/cardano-node]$ start-cluster
workbench:  cabal-inside-nix-shell mode enabled, calling cardano-* via cabal run (instead of using Nix store)
 10 days ago 65422ff37 HEAD -> master, origin/nightly, origin/master, origin/HEAD Merge #3816
workbench:  prebuilding executables (because of useCabalRun)
workbench:    prebuilding cardano-node
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 build -- exe:cardano-node
workbench:    prebuilding cardano-cli
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 build -- exe:cardano-cli
workbench:    prebuilding cardano-topology
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 build -- exe:cardano-topology

workbench:  run | allocate | profile:  pre-supplied
workbench:  run | allocate | topology:  computed
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 run exe:cardano-topology -- --topology-output /Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/run/2022-05-02-17.18.plain.default-alzo/topology/topology-nixops.json --dot-output /Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/run/2022-05-02-17.18.plain.default-alzo/topology/topology.dot uni-circle --size 6 --loc LO
workbench:  run | allocate | genesis:  computed
realpath: /Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a: No such file or directory
workbench:  genesis:  cache entry at /Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a is incompatible:  layout version 'unknown' does not match current: March-14-2022
workbench:  genesis: preparing cache entry k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a:  miss (/Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a)
workbench:  genesis: generating due to cache-miss:  k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a @/Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 run exe:cardano-cli -- genesis create --genesis-dir /Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a/ --supply 6010000000000000 --testnet-magic 42 --gen-genesis-keys 0 --gen-utxo-keys 1
Command failed: genesis create  Error: /Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a/genesis.alonzo.spec.json: /Users/deano/.cache/cardano-workbench/genesis/k6-d1-0.006kD-0kU-e74709a/genesis.alonzo.spec.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

[nix-shell:~/plutus/cardano-node]$ sudo start-cluster
Password:
/nix/store/c6jc5fbkvr45p6wpdj5k7d3ldim1lymw-workbench-0.1/bin/backend.sh: line 58: WORKBENCH_BACKEND: unbound variable
/nix/store/c6jc5fbkvr45p6wpdj5k7d3ldim1lymw-workbench-0.1/bin/backend.sh: line 60: WORKBENCH_BACKEND: unbound variable
'''

and here is result of cardano-node install:

```
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
workbench:    prebuilding cardano-cli
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 build -- exe:cardano-cli
exprType TYPE: AssetName
exprType TYPE: AssetName
workbench:    prebuilding cardano-topology
/nix/store/m2ckif2l1xf3x9y91wgczlah2snvbicw-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.6.2.0/bin/cabal --project-file=/Users/deano/plutus/cardano-node/.nix-shell-cabal.project -v0 build -- exe:cardano-topology


  Commands:
    * nix flake lock --update-input <iohkNix|haskellNix> - update nix build input
    * cardano-cli - used for key generation and other operations tasks
    * wb - cluster workbench
    * start-cluster - start a local development cluster
    * stop-cluster - stop a local development cluster
    * restart-cluster - restart the last cluster run (in 'run/current')
                        (WARNING: logs & node DB will be wiped clean)
'''

cardano-cli etc are working
````

Answer (score 0):

I have used the local cluster from cardano-node many times and on several different installs (1.34.1 & 1.33.1) and did not encouter the issue you are having.   No need to run start-cluster from sudo, so you can rule this out.

It sounds like there may be an issue with an invalid nix cache somewhere, so maybe you should try to clear/delete your nix store and start fresh?

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Cleaning_the_nix_store